# Yarn start or npm start or npm run start don't initialize the application

Tags: reactjs, node.js, yarnpkg, react-tsx

I started a new react project and started developing, for a period of time everything was fine and running normally. One day after restarting my Windows 10, when I went back to the project and ran the `yarn start` command, the console just showed the message
`project-name@0.1.0 start react-scripts start`
and the application did not initialize.

I've already tried updating the dependencies, I've tried running `npm audit fix --force` and nothing worked. I already deleted the `node_modules` folder and ran `yarn install`, it didn't work either. I deleted the `node_modules` folder again and ran npm install and it still doesn't work, it doesn't start the server. I would like to know if anyone has experienced this and knows how to resolve it.
I tried deleting the project folder and cloning again doing the installation step by step and it didn't work too. I even tried to create another project and copy the components, pages and still not working.

[folders path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQwTI.png)

[yarn start running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOA9H.png)

[npm start running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXpef.png)

[npm run start running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFauM.png)

Answer (score 0):

How did you scaffold the project?
What does the package.json look like?